# How to resolve PHP page not found on LiteSpeed server

Tags: php, litespeed

I have the following layout of a PHP files

```
├── classes/
├── migrations/
├── public/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── scripts/
│   ├── styles/
│   └── index.php
├── sample/
└── templates/
```

I wasn't sure how to put this on my server so I put the files from `public` into my `public_html` folder (which is what my cPanel already had).

Also, I put the other directories on the same level as `public_html` so as to maintain the regular structure of the project.

As such, I end up with this:

```
├── (some cPanel directory and files)
├── classes/
├── migrations/
├── public_html/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── scripts/
│   ├── styles/
│   └── index.php
├── sample/
├── templates/
└── (other cPanel directory and files)
```

Now, all other pages returns a HTTP status code 404 except the index page.

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, the project I'm trying to deploy is available at https://github.com/srv-twry/Quizzer.

Comment: Can you change the document root of your website?

Comment: I'm not sure, its cpanel. I will see

Comment: Target your website at http://example.com/index.php, does that work?  Can you access logs?  Do any Php files behave as expected when placed in the document root?

Comment: Going to the index.php in public_html works fine as my document root, but all other links point to 404.

Comment: Perhaps you need some redirection with a .htaccess and rewrite rules?  Assuming this server is Apache.  How do you run your site when developing?

Comment: It is working on index.php (as in it looks to be using your code), it's just that your routing doesn't account for index.php in the URL.  All you are missing is some rewrite rules I reckon.

Comment: Try something like this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57316/89012 , however it looks like you are running a litespeed server, so configuration may be different.  Check the manual and/or your hosting provider.

Comment: @Jimmy: what's you PHP version please?

Comment: @Progrock You genius! Thank you it works. If you want to add as an answer i will accept?

Comment: As a side note, you might give your project more flexibility/reusability by dropping the requires and using an autoloader.  See also PSR-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your source there is no `.htaccess`, and it sounds as if redirection is missing.

You'll need to route appropriate URLs through your front controller - `index.php`.

With Apache style servers you could use `modrewrite` and a `.htaccess` file.

As a starting point, create a `.htaccess` with the rules below - you may need to tweak for your individual needs;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Code copied from [Webmasters Stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57316/89012).